# Skipping else statement in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2012, if-statement

Why is the last `else` statment skipped in the following method in VS C++ ? I have correctly overloaded the `<` operator so there is no issues there. In fact, when I take this same function and recompile it in XCode it does what it suppose to perfectly as the `else` statement is executed. Why is this ?

```
void insert(Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t)
        {
            if (t == nullptr)
                t = new BinaryNode{ x, nullptr, nullptr };
            else if (x < (t->element))
                insert(x, t->left );
            else if ((t->element) < x)
                insert(x, t->right);
            else
                t->element.merge(x.getEnzymes());  
        }
```

Comment: you could always add another else if, since there's only one other scenario.

Comment: We need enough code to reproduce the problem. Can you create an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)?

Comment: "I have correctly overloaded the `<` operator" - are you sure it's correct? Can we see it? Moreover, can we see a complete (but minimal) test case to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: please show your complete test case that runsdifferently in the both environments. *complete* means compilable code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I can't upload the actual code b/c my professor is really strict about plagiarism...I will try to replicate the problem with dummy code.

Comment: I'm guessing you say "skipped" because you stepped through the code when `x==t->element` and you didn't hit the last else block. Just to make sure you're debugging the right problem, I would add at the top of the function something like this: `if(t&&t->element==x) cout<<"SAME: "<<x<<"=="<<t->element<<endl;` and put a breakpoint on your last block `t->element.merge(x.getEnzymes())`. It may just be that you never hit that block because you never actually had a case where `x==t->element`. What's the actual type of x? (for instance if it's a `double` , it can be tricky to do equality tests..)

Comment: @GuiRava Actual problem does exist. When I compile the exact same program in Xcode the function does hit the else statement. For what I see, there is nothing wrong with my code(it does what it is suppose to in Xcode) but some form of issue exits in Visual Studio...I am trying to replicate the issue so I can post some dummy code here to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like code optimization. C++ loves to "overoptimize" it and if it thinks this else will never be hit, then it will not even compile that part of code.
Also add { } for each if. It's easier for the parser to parse those if statements with them.
And you can split it into completely separate ifs.

Comment: code optimization does not influence code behaviour. if it does it is a compiler bug (returnvalue optimization is the only exception to this rule)

Comment: @SashaGlover: Actually what does what? Apart from copy/move elision (which doesn't apply here), optimisation must follow the "as-if" rule and produce the same behaviour as unoptimised code. If the behaviour changes due to optimisation, then the compiler is buggy.

Comment: a) Code optimization is not going to change logic. You would have a seriously flawed compiler if it was the case. This is 2014, not 1950. b) C++ itself doesn't optimize anything, compilers do. and c) It is NOT easier for the parser to parse with or without curly braces ! it may be easier for YOU to read, but the parser has no problem with that!